# List of links in an article

Tags: navigation

I want to add a field on my type of content which allows authors to select a link in a list. If author doesn't find the good link, he can directly add it and name it.

The list has to be composed with the name (title) of all links saved by all the authors of my site. All authors have to be able to add directly a new link in this list.

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think "feature from scratch" is something you'll be able to get here. Not when it isn't anything that seems obvious, widely needed. What you describe seems like tags with additional url field, but that's just my guess - dunno if it is te way that would help you, and writing full manual about how I would go about it would be a bit too long for Q&A format.

Comment: Actually, i'm pretty sure taxonomy is part of my solution but I really don't know how to link a term with an external url.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a content type for the link and then there are two options I can think of:

- Linkit, but I'm not sure it has a create option
- Nodereference with a module like [Node Reference Create](https://www.drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) or [References Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Taxonomy and then [Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) with [References Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog). Actually you can do it with several different modules for the Dialog, last project I've used this one and I like it.

You create a Taxonomy term, add your fields ([Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) is your friend). On you Content you insert a new field as Entity Reference. If you want to print not only the name of the term (as I think you will) you might need to create a Entity Reference View (it's a views display type), to render your fields.